# Elixir Ecto - how to render associated

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm looking at the [Ecto manual](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3) for the many-to-many schema function.

I want to get a list of recipes and include all of the tags that they are associated with.  I'm using this to retrieve them

```
def list_recipes do
  Repo.all(Recipe) |> Repo.preload(:tags)
end
```

I'm using the Phoenix framework and the the boiler-plate from `mix phx.gen.json` to display it, like this:

```
def render("index.json", %{recipes: recipes}) do
  %{data: render_many(recipes, RecipeView, "recipe.json")}
end
```

I know that I am retrieving the tags correctly (checked in `iex`), but they don't get returned in the json obviously because they're not included in the boilerplate template/view.

What is the best way to modify the boilerplate view/template to include the tags in the index of recipes?  Are there any good examples of how to do this?

Comment: There is some useful info in the [Phoenix Guides](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/views.html#rendering-json), search for `render_many`.

Comment: (Marking as duplicate as OP suggested in a comment here.)